# rsync freezes in macos ventura

Tags: terminal, ssh, rsync, ventura

I often `ssh` to a server or directly `rsync` some folder there to my local machine without any special config. After upgrading to MacOS Ventura, they no longer work. `rsync` just freezes after asking my password (asking password here is expected). With [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368561), I managed to make `ssh` work but not for `rsync`.
I'm using the base system's `rsync` (release 2.6.9) and it works if only on my local machine.
The commands not working with the server are like the following.

```
rsync someone@server:~/single_file ./
rsync -zavh someone@server:~/folder/ ./local_folder
```

Comment: How did you get ssh to work?

Comment: @mmmmmm I just followed the answer linked.

Comment: Note that rsync is over 10 years old so might have issue. I would try with a version from a package manager e.g. Homebrew, Macports. Nix